# Эффект плавной смены цвета элементов фиксированной навигации при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, css

Есть фиксированная навигация. Первый блок с цветным изображением, следующий блок белый.

Нужно чтобы цвет элементов в навигации (ссылки, кнопка) менялся в зависимости от цвета фона. Но только так, чтобы смена цветов была между черным и белым (черный на белом, белый на любом другом цвете).

Хочу добиться эффекта, который был бы с использованием `mix-blend-mode: difference` (плавная смена цвета, например на переходе между черным и белым - верхняя часть текста белая, нижняя черная).

На скрине пример с использованием `mix-blend-mode: difference`, как сейчас сделано у меня, нужно чтоб часть, которая на цветном фоне была белая.

Еще у меня есть в навигации логотип, который не должен менять цвет вообще, или, что было бы лучше, менять только часть цвета логотипа. Он в svg формате, 2 path - один белый, другой цветной. Если бы белая часть так же менялась между черным и белым, было бы прекрасно. `mix-blend-mode` я применяю к тегу, который оборачивает навигационные элементы (т.к если его применять к внутренним элементам, он не работает), поэтому к логотипу он тоже применяется

[image: Пример]

---

Заранее благодарю